# On WriteXml(fileName, writemode), Where is the fileName stored? How to create the file in the directory of .exe program?

Tags: c#, filenames

It's pretty much the topic
I have exactly this

```
tabelaEC0.WriteXml("config.xml" , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

I wanna know where the config.xml file is stored, since i didnt provide a full path,
also some people use a @ before the string, why is that?

How can i create the .xml file exactly where the directory of the executable of my final program will be?

(Winforms)

Update!:

I know now why it wasnt working, i was trying to save a file in the end of the program

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{ tabelaEC0.WriteXml(currentdirectory , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);   
  Application.Exit();
}
```

In this case it simply doesnt save the file (tried with another button and worked perfectly)
So the problem is the Form1 close, any hint?

Comment: WinForms, WPF or Console application?

Comment: I edited the question to remark it's winforms, is it differnet in other kinds? how odd

Comment: what type is tabelaEC0? I would assume, that the path comes from `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`. The @ before a string escapes backslashes (\), so @"C:\users" equals "C:\\users".

Comment: tabelaEC0 is a datatable, is that what you asked? if i use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` instead of `"config.xml"` what filename will it have? Isn't it missing the filename?

Comment: Put a label on your WinForm and write `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` to it.  Depending on your environment settings, I would expect it to either be the directory holding your source files, or the directory where your build's `.exe` goes.  Which, of course, assumes you're not simply running the .exe but running using visual studio.

Comment: What about this  `string currentdir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "config.xml";`, isn't it a suitable way to define path and filename?

Answer (score 0):

By default it should be written in the startup folder of your app. But this may change if you have already opened an OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog. To make sure the file is written to your application folder you can use this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "config.xml");
tabelaEC0.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: What if i'm still in coding form and run the `tabelaEC0.WriteXml("config.xml" , XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);` , where will the config.xml be? Is it missing the path? i believe i've seen some examples with only the filename written